# jQuery / PHP / WordPress: Autocomplete search "Foxycomplete" does not work

Tags: wordpress, search, plugins, widget, jquery-autocomplete

**Problem solved after I found an other template. Seems the previous one is incompatible.**

I'm using the Plugin [Foxycomplete](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/05/foxycomplete-advanced-autocomplete-search-images/) (advanced autocomplete search with images) - more specifically: I *want* to use it. I installed and enabled it. The developer explains one step like this:

> Enter the ID of the Form Input Field WITHOUT THE '#' on which you wish to apply the Autocomplete functionaliy. Defaults to the Regular "s".

I've even looked at the file foxycomplete.js, but I don't get it:

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {

    var inputField = site_data.inputField;
    var inputWidth = 0;

    var absPath = "";
    if(site_data.inputField == ""){
        inputField = "s";
    }
```

After this I took a look at the search form with firebug and this is the HTML-code:

```
<form action="http://localhost/sites/wordpress/" class="searchform" method="get">
<input type="text" value="" name="s" class="field">
<input type="submit" value="" name="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

Now I'm assuming that I have to change *class* = *"field"* to *id* = *"s"*, but I also do not know in which document I find the HTML part, I am a little stuck. If I do the change in firebug, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is to add following to your "input type" - **name="s", id="s"**. This worked for me on a Canvas theme, by woothemes, and should be cool with any other

as an example for your code:

```
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="" class="field">
```

edit: search form code location really different to each theme template. but in most cases it's in header or sidebar.